# How to save image to selected path from Stream object

Tags: c#, image, stream

The following code prompts the user to select a path to save an image from the pictureBox:

```
        Stream myStream;
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();            
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Portable Network Graphics|*.png";
        saveFileDialog1.Title = "Bild speichern";
        saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
        saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if ((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                this.picBox.Image.Save(myStream.ToString()); // is not getting the selected path
                myStream.Close();
            }
        }
```

But how can I get the path from myStream or save the image to the user defined location (with compatibility to .NET 3.5)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the selected file path from the save dialog then use...

```
saveFileDialog1.FileName;
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename.aspx) for more information on this property

You don't need to worry about using a Stream for this task.

Just to be clear, here is what your code should be...

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();            
saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Portable Network Graphics|*.png";
saveFileDialog1.Title = "Bild speichern";
saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    this.picBox.Image.Save(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
}
```

Comment: Works now, thanks. But I noticed if you have e.g. a folder called test and want to save the file as test then you change to the folder instead of saving it. You have to add .png to save it as test.png

Comment: @jack, If I understand correctly then I think in this case you would need to specify the file extension when typing in the SaveDialog to avoid folder navigation

Answer (score 1):

you can work with the `SaveFileDialog.FileName` only, no need for separated streams, try this:

```
using (var saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog())
{
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Portable Network Graphics|*.png";
    saveFileDialog1.Title = "Bild speichern";
    saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
    saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        picBox.Image.Save(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
string path = Path.GetDirectory(saveFileDialog1.Filename);
this.picBox.Image.Save(saveFileDialog1.Filename);
```

You really don't need a stream to do that :)

Comment: and what do you need path for? ;)

Comment: @musefan: it's not useful, but in some part of OP question ,path was requested. I put it here just to show the user how it can be done. OP is probably unexperienced with C#, so I wanted to give him one more info ;)

Comment: I don't think the directory path is what the OP meant, but no harm in teaching extra knowledge I suppose :)

Answer (score 0):

How's this?

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Portable Network Graphics|*.png";
saveFileDialog1.Title = "Bild speichern";
saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    (using FileStream fStr = new FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Create))
    {
        this.picBox.Image.Save(fStr);
        fStr.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: No need for FileStream, and no need to Close FileStream when you have a using statement (which is incorrectly coded by the way)